# React native select: Access key / index of selected option

Tags: html, reactjs, select, drop-down-menu

I have this implemented native select as a dropdown component. I can access the selected value with `e.target.value`. How do I either access the key value or the index of the mapped options:

```
<div className={`dropdown ${className} ${isInline ? "dropdown--inline" : ""}`}
style={{ width: width + "px", backgroundColor: styles!.dropdownBackgroundColor, borderColor: styles!.borderColor }}
                    >
    <select className="dropdown__portable-select"
         onChange={e => this.selectItem(e.target.value, true, e.target.index)} value={JSON.stringify(selectedValue)} // This line
                        >
    {selectedValue === unselectedValue && unselectedValue !== undefined ?
       <option value="">{unselectedValue}</option>
       : null}
    {options.map((o: any, index: number) => (
      <option key={index} value={JSON.stringify(o)}>{this.renderValue(o)}</option>
    ))}
  </select>
  <div className="dropdown__spacer" style={{ backgroundColor: styles!.borderColor }} />
  <div className="dropdown__icon-container" style={{ color: styles!.iconColor }}>
    <SvgIcon className="dropdown__icon" iconName="material-design/arrow_down_thin" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue is specifically this line:

```
onChange={e => this.selectItem(e.target.value, true, e.target.index)} value={JSON.stringify(selectedValue)}
```

e.target.index obviously doesn't exist. Either does e.target.key to address the key={index} in the map function.

How do I access the key or the index property on select ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is HTML property called [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) that you can access on a `select` element.

```
this.selectItem(e.target.value, true, e.target.selectedIndex)
```

You cannot access the `key` because it's a special attribute managed by React.